# Why is it possible that setState can be placed anywhere?

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I know that these two are the same.

```
counter++;
setState((){});
```

```
setState((){
  counter++;
};
```

but why does it work?

```
setState((){});
counter++;
```

I can see the change of counter even I changed it after calling setState function.

Comment: what i do get from doc is *Calling [setState] notifies the framework that the internal state of this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface in this subtree, which causes the framework to `schedule a [build]` for this [State] object*, >> ``schedule a [build]``

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to do `count++` inside the `setState`.

If you look at the documentation/code https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html, you'll see that the only line that matters is `_element!.markNeedsBuild();`.

`setState()` will basically rebuild your widget. And since you modified the instance of your widget with `count++`, the updated count will appear on the screen.

`setState` takes a callback and it is recommended to apply your state modifications inside it as it provides some useful error messages that will help you when debugging if you are doing something wrong.

Comment: It doesn't fully explain why the last example also works fine

Comment: When `_element!.markNeedsBuild();` is called, the build is not called right away. It just _"marks"_ this widget as _"dirty"_, and at the next frame, your widget will be rebuilt.
But your callback will finish before the next frame is called. Dart is mono threaded and your entire app runs in 1 thread. So your method will have to finish before the next build can be started.

Comment: Then calling setState first is highly discouraged.
Thanks for the comment @valentinVignal

Comment: I think the reason the last example work is - setState() is synchronous call - it means that Flutter framework will be notified that your widget needs rebuild (by calling markNeedsBuild) - but the framework does not have a chance to actually rebuild it until your function is done - i.e. your counter++ call will need to finish first. If you made async call after setState(), and did counter++ after that async call - it might happen that the Framework squeezes it's rebuild before your async call.